# CONTRACT in Solidity Compiler does not stay in Price Consumer, it reverts back to Aggregator

Tags: solidity, compiler

CONTRACT in Solidity Compiler does not stay in Price Consumer, it reverts back to Aggregator?

Please assist with this question.

Comment: Hi Robaer, could you give more information? Perhaps some screenshots of exactly what's going on? There isn't enough information to go off of here.

Comment: OK thanks Patrick. As I said I am new to this. I'm listening to the speaker at the moment. I will look back at it and make sense of it before I respond. Thanks!